# How to set http response code in Parse Server cloud function?

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code, http-response-codes

A parse server cloud function is defined via

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {..});
```

on the response, I can call `response.success(X)` and `response.error(Y)`, and that sets the http response code and the body of the response.

But how do I define a different code, like *created* (201)?
And how do I set the headers of the response?

thanks, Tim

Comment: For Errors, call `response.error(myError)` where `myError = new Parse.Error();` and you can set both the `code` and `message` properties. I do not know how to set a custom code for success.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I already saw the error function. I would like to return a CREATED instead of an OK. Maybe, I can set 201, CREATED as the "error"-code..

Comment: That wouldn't be advised, as it will result in some very muddled logs. Your response return object can be any valid JSON object. So, you could create your own object with the fields `code` and `value`, similar to how those errors are formatted, and pass those back in the success handler. I'll add this as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are allowed to return any valid JSON from `response.success()`.  Therefore, you could create an object with fields such as `code`, `message`, and `value`, so you can set the code, give it a string descriptor, and pass back the value you normally would, if there is one. This seems to accomplish what you need, though you will have to keep track of those codes across your platforms. I recommend looking up standard http response codes and make sure you don't overlap with any standards.

Comment: this solution is deprecated now.